# Converting from Scala.WrappedArray to a List<>

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, lambda

I've a piece of code as follows:

```
List<Integer> indexes = joinedCols
            .map(x-> ((Tuple2)x)._1)
            .collect();

    return indexes;
```

I would expect `indexes` to be of type `List<Integer>` however, when I check it with a debugger I see it's a type of `WrappedArray`. So, it doesn't behave like a `List` and causes errors when I want traverse over the returned list as `for (Integer i : indexes)`. How can I return the underlying list as a type of `List<Integer>` in this case ?

Comment: Not a solution but a workaround I found is traversing over the list like for(Object i : indexes).

Comment: What is the type of joinedCols?

Comment: @puhlen JavaPairRDD

Comment: I had the same issue but my solution was pretty bad. I used a `for` loop too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however, when I check it with a debugger I see it's a type of `WrappedArray`

What you see in the debugger is the *class* of the value, but it implements the `List` interface. So it behaves as a `List` (but note that many operations in `List` interface are optional and not supported here).

> and causes errors when I want traverse over the returned list as `for (Integer i : indexes)`

That's because you remove the type information by casting to raw `Tuple2`. Assuming you have a `JavaPairRDD<Integer, SomeType>`, just removing the cast should give you a `List<Integer>` and allow iterating like this.